# Modify request path info

Tags: php, yii

Now, let me guess what y'all may be thinking... "It's a bad idea to modify the path info before it's processed. Why would you ever want to do that? This is malicious behavior!!!"

I am trying to get a `controller/action` representation of my previous URL; gotten through `Yii::app()->getRequest()->getUrlReferrer()`.

[From Yii 2 issues](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1401), it's possible to set the path info for a new request and parse that request. However, from the Yii 1 source, the only methods which deals with the path info are `getPathInfo()` and `decodePathInfo()`. If there was a `setPathInfo()`, I could have used that and the `urlManager->parseUrl()` to achieve this. But we aren't allowed to set the path info.

How can I arrive at a `controller/action` representation of my previous URL?

Comment: i'm little confuse... so what you want exactly... need previous url `controller/action` info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii does not allow the `CHttpRequest` object live past the parsing of the routes. And creating a  new `CHttpRequest` is impossible after the app is created.

I realized the only way to go about this is the vanilla `Yii::app()->controller->action` object. From this, I could get the module, controller and action ID for the specific URL.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it's good way to find previous location but will give you incomplete url.

You can try this way in Yii 1.0 -

if your url like - `www.domain.com?r=site/page`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['r']) && !empty($_REQUEST['r'])){
    $previous_location = $_REQUEST['r'];
    Yii::app()->user->setState('previous_location', $previous_location);
}
```

Another way-

```
$controller_name = Yii::app()->controller->id;
$action_name = Yii::app()->controller->action->id;

Yii::app()->user->setState('previous_location', $controller_name.'/'.$action_name);
```

so you can find out your previous location by -

```
echo Yii::app()->user->getState('previous_location');
```

It's may be help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I can get the previous page using `Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer`. But I need to parse this URL to get its controller and action. For example, if the `urlReferrer` is example.com/admin/posts/view/id/1, I should get some sort of array as a result like `array('module' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view')`